# How can I render rows of data within a table that is being held as an Object of arrays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i'm getting an API call response and its coming back as an object of arrays. I'm trying to make a table and have each value of the array within each array within the object display its information. The api response hold information from a game of baseball of each pitch of the game. https://github.com/zitrosolrac/AstrosApi
i've tried using the map function, on the array but i'm not sure how to use the map function within the render/return call.

---

attr1 attr2 attr3 ....

1    ball   astros ....
.      .      .      ...
.      .      .      ...
.      .      .     ...
.      .      .     ...

Comment: Please share code, your attempt and format of data that is being returned from API call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object has keys inside it and it was not handled in your code. Update your ApiDisplay.js as follows and it will work

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const ApiDisplay = ({ data }) => {
  console.log("data", data);
  //return null;
  return (
    <>
      {data &&
        Object.keys(data).map((key) =>
          Object.keys(data[key]).map((key1) => 
          <div key={data[key][key1].event_id}>
              <div>
                <h4>
                  <b>{data[key][key1].pitcher_name}</b>
                </h4>
                <p>{data[key][key1].batter_name}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ApiDisplay;
```

I have updated your codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-wright-u6t0n?file=/src/components/ApiDisplay.js

Comment: Hey Rabeeh, this seems to work but I'm wondering if you could help me figure out how to display all the data in a table where the attr are listed as column headers. Then, I would need to figure out how to filter the data by pitch type. That's what i'm working on right now.

Comment: @enarc4ever i didnt understand the question. Could you provide as a screenshot how you want the data to be displayed in page?

Comment: https://medium.com/how-to-react/create-a-table-like-datatables-in-react-using-react-table-fbea64eca3ac If you go to this page, you can see the desired table outcome. I'm trying to use ReactTable built-in component but I'm not sure how to pass in the data in the proper format. @rabeehMohammed

Comment: `{data &&
        Object.keys(data).map((key) =>
          Object.keys(data[key]).map((key1) => ( 
            <ReactTable data=[Object.keys(data[key]) columns=[Columns] />          ))
        )}`

Comment: Hey I was wondering if you could help me figure out how to format the data into a table. You can visit this link to view my updated work. https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-glade-b5liq?file=/src/Table.js

Comment: I keep getting this error TypeError
Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance